# Check if username already exists pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I wanted to know if there is any query that can let me know if username already exists using firestore in python? when a user register his/ her email, if email already exists it show that it's already existing. In the same way , is there any built in function or any other method to know that username already exist? I am using pyrebase. If anyone knows a way please let me know.

Comment: If you are using Firebase authentication in order to register your users and proceed with the username creation by saving it on a document on firestore you could easily query for that username in your "users" collection for instance. On the other hand, pyrebase is implementing firebase auth, so maybe if a user is trying to create another user with a previously registered email, this will be catched by the library, so you just need to catch tis error and then update it at the front-end. what have you attempted so far? what is the structure of your documents describing your users?

Comment: Hi, yes i found the solution. I can find username from database only and check if it exists or not. As for email firebase handles that itself. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Awesome, I'd recommend you to post your solution here so maybe in the future other users can use your approach as a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query and check if there is a match.

```py
users_by_name = db.child("users").order_by_child("name").get()
```

I suggest that you check that link on how to retrieve information using [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#retrieve-data).